# is the whole url being sent on a dns inquiry?

Tags: networking, dns

for example when I put this on my browser,
https://superuser.com/  **questions/715/is-dns-query-http-access**
does browser strips off the bold part and send a DNS inquiry to dns server containing only superuser.com??
in other word I wanna know how far the DNS server has access to what I am browsing?

Comment: *"I want to know how far the DNS server has access to what I am browsing?"* - As mentioned below, DNS servers really only know the IP address/domain name of the sites you request (i.e. the bold portion isn't part of the query). But anyone who is genuinely interested in monitoring your internet traffic is likely to try and use more than just DNS queries anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

DNS servers only process domain names or IP addresses. The protocol, path, and query string are not sent to the DNS server.

[RFC 1035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) Section 4.1.2 defines the question section format for domain names.